# Did native HTML ever auto-disable links to the current page, and if so how do I achieve this?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink

I vividly remember doing this 10 years ago when I first started writing HTML and the only CSS I knew was styling (not selectors) and I knew no JavaScript, but [the solutions](https://css-tricks.com/pointer-events-current-nav/) I keep finding have only been around for the past few years.

I cannot test my hypothesis, but based on conjecture, I believe that I was using frames with a table-of-contents:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<body>
<frameset cols="50%,50%">
  <frame src="toc.html">
  <frame name="1" src="1.html">
  <noframe>
    Frames are disabled for this browser.
  </noframe>
</frameset> 
</body>
</html>
```

And here's my table of contents:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<body>
    <a href="1.html" target="1">1.html</a><br />
    <a href="2.html" target="1">2.html</a><br />
</body>
</html>
```

But I am getting the noframes content on every browser I've tried: Firefox, Chrome, and Safari:

[image: Frames are disabled for this browser]

But when I did have this working, it would disable the link if I happened to have navigated to it in a frame:

[image: Disabled toc.html link]

But now, it always shows the link:

[image: Link is not disabled when I am on the same page]

I really want to know what the solution I did in the past was, but if it has to do with frames, it is very much dead. I am looking for a pure HTML/CSS solution, but I might be able to fit a little JavaScript in.

Comment: CSS (which you didn't tag your question with) can only change the styling of the link but not detect the URL or disable anything. For that you'd need JavaScript (which you also didn't tag your question with).

Comment: @j08691 No, completely incorrect. This is functionality that is inherent to HTML. I have seen this functionality on other websites with no JavaScript or CSS applied.

Comment: You're right. What do I know? Good luck!

Comment: @j08691 With 100k reputation, you could have easily edited those tags into my question yourself. Instead, you come into my question and condescend to me about improper tagging of my question (and probably followed it with a resentful -1). Not very professional behavior at all. My point is that I have seen this behavior without any special CSS or JavaScript in an HTML page, therefore I did not believe there to be a need for those tags.

Comment: I'm sorry that you feel that I was condescending towards you. I was pointing out that your original tags `html` and `hyperlink` alone will not allow what you are describing (and if you don't feel that those tags are needed, then why did you add them?). I won't edit a question's tags based on my comments unless they're confirmed. For example, PHP can do what you want, but you didn't mention *any* server side code, so I won't go adding such a tag. Also, I didn't downvote you, and since voting is completely anonymous, I don't know why you'd claim that.

Comment: I am very sorry myself @j08691; I just have this visceral, clear memory of doing this 10 years ago when I first started writing HTML (and I didn't know CSS selectors, and I definitely didn't know JavaScript), and now I'm bombarded by the fact that the pure-HTML implementation I had used is a mere fabrication and my memory is nothing but a lie. It is not this simple problem that has me so tense, but the fact that my own mind is lying to me that is causing me stress.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you'll need some sort of processing: javascript, or some dynamic language like PHP. Basically, what you need to do is add a CSS class - something like "visited" - which includes greying out or whatever styling you want - which you apply to the link at page load. The javascript/php/etc. would be the one to check whether you're already on the given page.

Comment: Bear in mind that you can of course achieve the same result without external stylesheets or active JS: as long as your PHP or other generation language adds the style="color:grey" tag. Using CSS fully would be more elegant though.

Comment: I'm pushing these HTML files to a content server, so I can't use PHP.

Comment: In that case, modify the HTML pages themselves, directly: change all the `<a href='page.html'> within page.html`. The answer below describes how to make a link not go anywhere, while to make it look different you should use `style=` tags. There are non-CSS ways to change styles, but these are severely obsoleted by now. Best thing is something like `style="font-weight:bold; color:black; text-decoration:none;"`.

Comment: You could also, of course, just change the links on the specific pages to use a `<span>` rather than an `<a>` tag in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Since it sounds like you have static HTML pages, a strictly HTML way to "disable" a link can be done like the following example:

```
Before: <a href="3.html">Page Three</a>
After: <a>Page THree</a>
```

#### Clarification:

It is still the recomendation of most people that you use Javascript and CSS to perform this requirement. Which is as simple as:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" style="cursor: default;">123n</a>
```